# Bad performance in MYSQL 5.7 after Upgrade from 5.6.27

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7

I've got a query like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.nr = table_b.a_nr
ORDER BY table_b.name
```

Under MYSQL 5.7.9, this query takes about 120sek. 
Under 5.6.27 "only" ~25 sek. There are 500000 rows in table_a. Why is 5.7.9 that slow?

I know, Mysql can not use an index for sorting, cause of the joined column.

I made test with InnoDB and the MYISAM engine with the same result.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `NR` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `LIEFNR` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `BEZ1` CHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `BEZ2` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SBEZ1` CHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SBEZ2` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MENGENEINH` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VKPREIS` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREISEINH` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREISEINH_IST` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREISEINHVK` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREISEINHVK_IST` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `EAN` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EANUSER` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKPREIS` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `LISTENEKPREIS` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `BESTELLNR` CHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `LANGTEXT` longtext,
  `KATSEITE` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HERSTARTNR` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HWGR` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `WGR` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MWST` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKRABGR` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VKRABGR` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VERPAMENGE` DECIMAL(5,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PACKINH` DECIMAL(7,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MARK` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `UEBERGABE` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GEWICHT` DECIMAL(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `RABATT` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `ARTUID` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PREINH2` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NPREIS2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREINH3` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NPREIS3` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREINH4` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NPREIS4` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PREINH5` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NPREIS5` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `NPREISFAK` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `EKSTAFM1` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKSTAFP1` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `EKSTAFM2` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKSTAFP2` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `EKSTAFM3` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKSTAFP3` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `EKSTAFM4` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKSTAFP4` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `EKSTAFM5` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EKSTAFP5` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `EKSTAFFAK` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `PREISEMPF` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `UMRFAKTOR` DECIMAL(12,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `LIEFILN` CHAR(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MODE` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HERSTNAME` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VERWEIS` CHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MINDBEST` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `AENDDAT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ANLAGEDAT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `LASTIMPORT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `NOTUEBERN` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PERSBEZPREIS` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AKTUELLTEMP` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NICHTAKTUELL` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ZUSATZEAN1` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ZUSATZEAN2` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ZUSATZEAN3` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ZUSATZEAN4` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ZUSATZEAN5` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AUSLAUFARTI` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PAFAKTOR` DECIMAL(13,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `PREISFOKUS` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IMPORTKENNZ` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MATCHARTNR` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `EXPORTFREIGABE` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MD5` CHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `KEYWORDS` longtext,
  `SHOPTEXT` longtext,
  `BEMERKUNG` CHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SYS_UID` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SYS_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `P_ARTI01` (`SYS_UID`),
  KEY `P_ARTI02` (`LIEFNR`,`NR`,`MD5`),
  KEY `P_ARTI03` (`LIEFNR`,`BEZ1`),
  KEY `P_ARTI04` (`LIEFNR`,`HWGR`,`WGR`),
  KEY `P_ARTI05` (`EAN`,`LIEFNR`),
  KEY `P_ARTI06` (`AENDDAT`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `A_NR` CHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_FNR` CHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_NAME1` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_NAME2` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_EINHEIT` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_MENGEING` DECIMAL(2,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A_VERPACK` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_WGR` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_WGRU` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_ECLASS` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LAGORT` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_MENGEINH` DECIMAL(6,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A_VK1` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK3` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK4` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK5` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK6` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK7` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK8` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VK9` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB1` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB3` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB4` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB5` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB6` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB7` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB8` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKB9` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VKBED1` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED2` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED3` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED4` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED5` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED6` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED7` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED8` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VKBED9` CHAR(18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_ERLDM1` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM3` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM4` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM5` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM6` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM7` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM8` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLDM9` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLPRO1` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO2` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO3` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO4` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO5` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO6` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO7` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO8` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_ERLPRO9` DECIMAL(7,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_LIEFER1` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LIEFER2` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LIEFER3` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LIEFER4` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LIEFER5` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_EK1` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_EK2` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_EK3` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_EK4` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_EK5` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_EKVKPROZ` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BON1` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BON2` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BON3` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BON4` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BON5` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RAB1` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RAB2` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RAB3` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RAB4` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RAB5` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BESTNR1` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BESTNR2` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BESTNR3` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BESTNR4` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BESTNR5` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BESDAT1` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_BESDAT2` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_BESDAT3` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_BESDAT4` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_BESDAT5` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_EAN` CHAR(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_POSKEN` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BESTAND` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_MAXBE` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_MELDEBE` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_UMSASTK` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_UMSJA` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_UMSLF` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_UMSQU` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_UMSVJ` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_CNTLF` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_CNTJA` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_CNTQU` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_CNTVJ` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKLF` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKQU` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKJA` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKSLF` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKSQU` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKSJA` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_UMSDATUM` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_EKDATUM` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_ANLAGE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_LTZAEND` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_LDAT` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_LZEIT` CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_MWSTSCHL` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VSTSCHL` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_INVENTUR` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_GERAET` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SERIENNR` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_INOUTPUT` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_FAKTURA` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_RABATT` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_RABGR1` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RABGR2` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RABGR3` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RABGR4` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RABGR5` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ERLKTO` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DELETED` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SNAME1` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SNAME2` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SEINHEIT` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SPRACHE` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_URLAND` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LANGTEXT` longtext,
  `A_LANGTEXTANSI` longtext,
  `A_GEBINDE` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_POSANZ` DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_DATANORM` CHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_HANDGW` DECIMAL(9,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_ARTNR` CHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_ARTIPOS` CHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LAGPOS` CHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SERLKTO` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_EGKTO` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_EKDURCH` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_DBESTAND` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_RESBEST` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_KZMENGE` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_KZFEST1` DECIMAL(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_KZFEST2` DECIMAL(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_KZFEST3` DECIMAL(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_STDVERR` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKVORJA` DECIMAL(13,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `A_PROZFRA` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_BESZEIT` DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A_PROVSATZ` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_LADELIST` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PAVKN1` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKN2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKN3` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKN4` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKN5` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKB1` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKB2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKB3` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKB4` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PAVKB5` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PRODSC` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PRODZEIT` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_PRODLI` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_MINPROV` DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_TYP` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_EKSTK` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_EKDM` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_STFAKTOR` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_ABSATZ` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_KVER` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_ABESTAND` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_LOHNVJ` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_LOHNSUMM` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_SUCHBEGRIFF` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_GFAKTOR` DECIMAL(8,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `A_GMEINH` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_IBEWERT` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_IBEWSTUND` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_LOHNSTD` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_MASCHSTD` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_SUCHTEXT` longtext,
  `A_SUCHTEXTANSI` longtext,
  `A_GERART` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_LAGER` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BEMERKUNG` CHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_KEINBEST` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PRODUKTION` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SKFJN` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART1` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART2` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART3` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART4` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART5` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART6` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART7` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART8` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKLART9` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSATZ1` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ2` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ3` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ4` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ5` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ6` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ7` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ8` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSATZ9` DECIMAL(8,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `A_AKSOLL1` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL2` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL3` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL4` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL5` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL6` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL7` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL8` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AKSOLL9` CHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_INAKTIV` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_AUTOINAKTIV` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_STCKOPT` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_FILIALE` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PRODMENG` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_SONDERART` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_BETONREZEPT` DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A_UEBERDECKUNG` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  `A_UEBERDECKUNG_R` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  `A_UEBERDECKUNG_O` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  `A_UEBERDECKUNG_U` DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  `A_MENGEFORMEN` DECIMAL(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A_TRANSLAGER` CHAR(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_GARANTIE` DECIMAL(4,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A_HERSTELLERNR` CHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_HERSTELLERNAME` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PREISFOKUS` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_MINDBESTMENGE` DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_NEUKALK` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PREISFLAG1` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PREISFLAG2` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_PREISFLAG3` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_KEINEXTTEXT` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_ZEN_KBEZ` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SHOP` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SHOP_NOSEARCH` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SHOPTEXTKD` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SHOPTEXTKD_TITEL` CHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SHOPBEZ` CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_METATITLE` CHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_METADESCR` CHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_METAKEYWORDS` CHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_GUTSCHEIN` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_SHOPARTNR` CHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_VSSF_FAKTOR` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VSSF_VON` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_VSSF_BIS` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_VSSF_A_FAKTOR` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `A_VSSF_A_VON` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_VSSF_A_BIS` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `A_ERFASSER` CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `A_COLSTATUS` CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SYS_ZENTRALE` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SYS_UID` CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `SYS_DATE` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `ARTIKEL01` (`SYS_UID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ARTIKEL02` (`A_NR`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL03` (`A_NAME1`,`A_NAME2`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL04` (`A_DATANORM`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL05` (`A_WGR`,`A_NAME1`,`A_NAME2`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL06` (`A_LAGPOS`,`A_NAME1`,`A_NAME2`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL07` (`A_ARTIPOS`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL08` (`A_SUCHBEGRIFF`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL09` (`A_EAN`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL10` (`A_FILIALE`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL11` (`A_FILIALE`,`A_NR`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL12` (`A_INAKTIV`,`A_NR`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL13` (`A_LAGER`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL14` (`A_ARTNR`),
  KEY `ARTIKEL15` (`A_HERSTELLERNR`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Sometimes it's quite useful. if you are linking some documents to costumer informations, you'll have unlinked dokuments.

Comment: Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE` information for both tables. Also, it seems a bit atypical to sort on a column from table on the right side of a left join.  Is it your intent to sort on a column with possible null values?

Comment: Please put table descriptions in the post iteself, not in linked site.

Comment: @Mike this would be about 380 lines of code

Comment: That is OK.  The preference is to have all relevant code in the question such that it is stored for future reference, as external links can break.

Comment: Did the migration to 5.7 overwrite configuration values of 5.6 you had before?

Comment: @mjh No. To verify the result, we tested on indentic machines. One with 5.7 and one with 5.6 and the same database.

Answer (score 0):

Use consistent definitions for columns being `JOINed` on.

Use `VARCHAR`, not `CHAR` unless the column is a constant length.

Use an extra table rather than putting "arrays" as columns:  A_AKSOLL9 (etc).

Did you set innodb_buffer_pool_size to a reasonable value when testing InnoDB?